# Jpeg, remove chroma, keep only luma without recompressing?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, jpeg, mogrify

Is it possible to strip down chroma information from a jpeg file without loss on the luma?

Ideally I'd like a smaller file-size, greyscale version of an existing and optimized image.

Comment: I am not really sure what you want, so this may not be relevant. But you can change the sampling factor with ImageMagick. See https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#sampling-factor

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the scans are not interleaved, you could update the SOF marker to have one scan and then delete the 2d and 3d scans from the input stream.